# MongoDB: Remove array elements from a document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm new to Mongo and thus trying to implement a use-case wherein I need to build a query to remove data from an array from inside a collection of documents.

Here is one of my documents:

```
{
"id" : 2,
"owners" : ["aa", "bb"]
}
```

Now I need to build a query to find all document records based on the owners and if present, remove them from the `owners` array.

For example, I sent `aa` in the query, then I need to remove that from all the documents that contains that owner.

I found somewhere this logic:

```
$db.coll.update({cond to identify document},{$pull:{'owners':{'aa':<>}}})
```

But don't understand how does this remove the data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query updates a collection by removing the matched `owners` from `owners` array. The update query contains three blocks,

```
db.coll.update(
        { },
        { $pull: { owners: "aa" } },
        { multi: true }
    )
```

first block  `{}`: it specify the query to find the documents, as we are considering all documents, we kept it blank

second block `{ $pull: { owners: "aa" } }`: This one is removing matching elements from `owners` array from all documents.

third block `{ multi: true }`: this block specifies that, we are considering update for all matching document, `{ multi: false }` will update only the first matched document

To learn more you can follow this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

Comment: thanks for replying. Can you please explain what exactly is happening here?

Comment: A better approach would be to use a query condition in your update method in which the update operation only updates the documents matched by the query and use an index, rather than do a full collection scan and checks for each document in the collection then do a `$pull` which could be potentially slow on large datasets. Your solution can be further improved by including the query as `db.coll.update(
    { "owners": "aa" },
    { "$pull": { "owners": "aa" } },
    { "multi": true }
)`

Comment: @chridam yes, it is true

Comment: Thanks very much gypsyCoder and chridam.